# Why are assets not precompiling with RAILS_ENV set?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sass

I've almost gone through every article on the web to fix this issue and nothing helped so far. 
Here's whats happening.

I use capistrano to deploy my app and everything was working great until yesterday. I couldn't get my assets precompiled no matter what.

So, when I do `rake assets:precompile` locally on on prod server just to check if the assets are getting precompiled at all, it all works fine.

However, when I do `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile` it fails. I tried with different environments but nothing worked out except omitting the RAILS_ENV. The problem I'm facing is that my latest changes are not reflecting in production.

Here is the trace of error

```
I, [2015-09-24T23:39:05.138170 #6733]  INFO -- : Writing  /home/pamio/dev/rails_apps/remote/valutme- storefront/public/assets/high_voltage/pages- 77d20ed7f226268c100e527b51cf0830.js
I, [2015-09-24T23:39:05.232937 #6733]  INFO -- : Writing /home/pamio/dev/rails_apps/remote/valutme-storefront/public/assets/home-77d20ed7f226268c100e527b51cf0830.js
I, [2015-09-24T23:39:05.458718 #6733]  INFO -- : Writing 
 ......................
rake aborted!
Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "...content: "\f105": expected " {", was "";"
(in /home/pamio/dev/rails_apps/remote/valutme- storefront/app/assets/stylesheets/admin.css.erb)
(sass):9628
/home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/sass- 3.4.10/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1165:in `expected'
/home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1101:in `expected'
/home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1096:in `tok!'
/home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:641:in `block'
/home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:711:in `declaration_or_ruleset'
/home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:661:in `block_child'
/home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:653:in `block_contents'
/home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:642:in `block'
/home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:635:in `ruleset'
/home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:660:in `block_child'
/home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:653:in `block_contents'
/home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:117:in `stylesheet'
/home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:42:in `parse'
/home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/engine.rb:393:in `_to_tree'
/home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/engine.rb:268:in `render'
/home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:24:in `evaluate'
/home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:103:in `render'
/home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:197:in `block in evaluate'
/home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/sprockets- 2.12.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `each'
/home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `evaluate'
/home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:25:in `initialize'
/home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `new'
/home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `build_asset'
/home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
/home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
/home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
/home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
/home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
/home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:211:in `block in find_asset'
/home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:257:in `benchmark'
/home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:210:in `find_asset'
/home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:119:in `block in compile'
/home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `each'
/home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `compile'
/home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:60:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:146:in `with_logger'
/home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:59:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/pamio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Also, What's the default rails environment for `rake assets:precompile` ? If the default is production then it should also work when supplied an explicit environment argument.

Can anyone let me know what's happening ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have a sass syntax error in storefront/app/assets/stylesheets/admin.css.erb. Moreover, compiling assets locally on your development environment is more forgiving than when you precompile for production. Check the syntax error!

Comment: The default for `RAILS_ENV` is `development`. Try compiling them in `production` mode locally on your dev machine.

Comment: Well, I have been using the same css files for ages now and I've never had any issues. As I said it started appearing since yesterday. @moeabdol what do you mean by forgiving ? Does it not check for syntax error in local. Also FYI when I run it locally with env set as development it stills fails with the same error. However works fine when no argument supplied as mentioned In the question.

Comment: @AlexeyShein I've tried at already. The trace is the outcome of that. You can see the back trace in my question

Comment: Is there any error on that line in `admin.css.erb`? Btw, did you move your project to a new folder lately? I can see that your project path contains a space (`valutme- storefront`), this also may cause some issues.

Comment: That's s typo. Sorry about that. Well, if there are errors then asset pre compile should complain even without env arguments. Right ? But it didn't. So I would say no.

Comment: you probably have 'config.assets.css_compressor = :sass' in your production.rb environment config and not elsewhere

Comment: @hamitron, no thats not there. I do not have this line in both prod and dev config files. The very basis for this question is that I can precompile my assets with setting any ENV but if I set the env to either development or production or even test for that matter, I get the error which  I dont otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried Running:

```
rake assets:clean RAILS_ENV=production    
rake assets:clobber RAILS_ENV=production
```

?

Comment: This is not an answer! This should rather go in the comments. Yes I've tried them already!